# Chrome extension Modal/Popup on click

Tags: google-chrome-extension

I want to dynamically generate some buttons on my `chrome extension` `default_popup` `HTML` page and I want on click to open a `model` in the middle of the screen NOT a new tab, I saw some other extensions having its options like this, and then display some info.

Comment: [this](https://www.w3schools.com/howto/tryit.asp?filename=tryhow_css_modal) might help.

Comment: i need for chrome extensions, it is different a modal opens inside the default_popup.html, i saw in some chrome extension app it opens it on the tab instead

Comment: A popup is just a div which is absolute/fixed positioned. I don't see any problem in having another popup in your default_popup.html.

Comment: because it will create it absolute to the default_popup.html page , not to tab window.

Comment: Those other extensions simply inject into the web page, something like iframe or a div. The standard browser_action popup CANNOT be moved from its standard position.

Comment: would you say its better to inject? because i wanna use some ajax calls from my extension panel , get some information in terms of documents and then when they are clicked to open some module type were i can better see the json, with the standard one i dont have acces to module thing. Would a possibility be to keep the standard browser_Action popup but when i click one of those json documents to open a new blank tab and then inject into that tab a module like div?I don want to open the json in a standard tab because it looks bad.

Answer (score 1):

I think the only possibility isto get rid of the defalt_popup and inject all my scripts through the background page straight into the html page.